# Obter o número de linhas e transformar em divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

Bom dia, recentemente eu estava escrevendo esse código e tive alguns problemas, eu gostaria de obter o número de linhas do conteúdo de uma div "contenteditable" e levar esses valores (números) para outra div.

**Segue o meu código simplificado:**

```js
 $(document).one('paste',function(e) {
  setTimeout(function() {
  var x = $('#input').contents().length;
       $("#line").append ('<div>'+x);
  },100);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div contenteditable="true" id="input" spellcheck="false"></div>
<div id="line"><div>0</div></div>
```

**Os resultados que eu estou obtendo quando o número de linhas em #input é 4:**

```
<div id="line">
    <div>0</div>
    <div>4</div>
</div>
```

**Simulação dos resultados que eu gostaria de obter quando o número de linhas em #input é 4:**

```
<div id="line">
    <div>0</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
</div>
```

Apenas lembrando que em `<div id="line"><div>0</div></div>` já temos um zero inicialmente.

Resumidamente o problema é que estou obtendo apenas uma div com o valor de todas as linhas, eu gostaria de ter uma div para cada linha.

Na espera de alguma ajuda, obrigado.

Comment: nao entendi muito bem ... será algo como isto? https://jsbin.com/pisozen/2/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: @balexandre Sim, seu exemplo é basicamente oque eu quero, por favor, poste-o como uma resposta, mais tarde eu verei as próximas e irei avaliar a melhor. Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pedido pelo comentário, aqui fica o exemplo.

Nomeadamente, apenas uso o `on("blur")` que significa, quando nao tem `focus`, ou seja, quando clica fora do input, e depois de contar as linhas, por cada linha, adiciono o `<div>` que pretende ...

```js
$(function() {
  $("#input").on("blur", function(evt) {
    // numero de linhas do conteudo
    var len = $(this).contents().length;
    // cria output
    draw(len);
  });
});

function draw(lines) {
  // limpa #line para que comece sem conteudo
  $("#line").empty();
  
  // adiciona <div>X</div> por cada linha
  for(i = 0; i < lines; i += 1)
    $("#line").append("<div>"+i+"</div>");
}
```

```css
#input {
  min-height: 100px;
  min-width: 100px;
  border: 1px dashed #bada55;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div contenteditable="true" id="input" spellcheck="false"></div>
<div id="line"><div>0</div></div>
```

Comment: Obrigado, sua resposta realmente me ajudou, porém eu gostaria de manter o "paste" pois preciso detectar os eventos "paste" do mouse e do teclado. Já tentei modificar algumas coisas, mas sem sucesso. Alguma solução?

Comment: Resolvido, linha modificada >> "$('#input').on('input paste',function(e)" obrigado mais uma vez!

Answer (score 2):

Sem o uso de jquery pode fazer algo assim:

```js
function criarDivs(input){
  // TODO:: validação do input
  let total = document.getElementById('input').innerText;
    
  for (let i=1; i<=total; i++){
    let div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerText = i;
    document.getElementById('line').appendChild(div);
  }
  
}
```

```css
#input{
  width:100px;
  height:20px;
  background-color:#ccc
}

#line div{
  background-color: gold;
  margin:4px;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true" id="input">4</div>
<button type="button" onclick="criarDivs()">CRIAR DIVS</button>
<div id="line"></div>
```

Comment: Alternativa interessante, supondo que não usa jquery, obrigado!